# -webkit-transition with display

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

Is there a way to use `-webkit-transition` with `display`?

I'm using CSS `display` to hide and show a navigations second level … but only `display: none` and `display: block` on `:hover` is a little un-sexy… a `ease` would be great (like `-webkit-transition: display 300ms ease-in;`)

I know that's fairly easy to do this with jQuery, but I'm currently trying to setup everything with CSS3 (i know: not all browsers do support it, but that's irrelevant for this one project I'm currently working on)

here's some code & structure: (the `li.menu1` has a `:hover` with `section.nav-menu1 {display: block;}`)

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <section class="nav-menu1">
            <h1 class="none">Level 2 Overlay</h1>
            <nav>
                <h2 class="none">Menu 1 Navigation</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Level 2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Level 2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Level 2-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show navigation structure? Or even example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `height` or `width` transition in order to show and hide second level menu. `Display` property is not supported by transitions.

There is an article at [ODC](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-show-and-hide/) with [something similar](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/1861/css-menu-ex4.html) to your needs. Also, I've [modified it a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/jTE6e/) in order to look more like menu item. Works perfect in Opera 10.7, without transitions in Firefox 3.6.12 and doesn't at all in Chrome 7.0.517.41.

I hope this will be useful as start point for your own animated menu.

**Update 1:**
[Your menu with ease-in transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/fMvZz/4/). Probably, I've got something wrong about it's structure. The problem is that transitions do not work with `auto`, so you have to manually specify final height.

**Update 2:**
Use opacity as transition property. On invisible element set visibility:hidden and visibility:visible  on visible. That will prevent from invisible clickable links. Also, visible-invisible transition doesn't work, don't know why. Have to work more om it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fMvZz/6/).

Comment: YEAH! Thx! … on hidden: <visibility:hidden; opacity: 0; -XY-transition: opacity 150ms ease-in;> and on the visible: <visibility: visible; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden;> … Thx!

Comment: The only keywords that work are colors. center, left, right, auto, etc are not transitioned (yet, I'd add) unfortunately.

Comment: Fades in great, but unfortunately the fade *out* doesn't work with this.

Comment: If you want to fade both out and in, you can use the workaround in this gist: https://gist.github.com/2933815

Comment: It should be noted that if you want this to work on an iOS device, as far as I'm aware it _has_ to use display: block; and display: none; to hide, which is a tad frustrating. It may be that jQuery or similar provides the most robust solution when animation and tablet / phone support are required.

Answer (score 18):

So I'm not sure I see all the pieces put together here. You want to animate opacity and visibility, with visibility having a delay so opacity is done before it triggers;

```
opacity: 0;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .5s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .5s;
transition: opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .5s;
visibility: hidden;
```

to

```
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
```

visibility will wait .5s and then switch over to hidden. You can even turn off the visibility transition on one side if you want it to fade both ways. (So that when fading in, the element is instantly visible instead of waiting .5s and transitioning.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an opacity transition, not a display transition for this. Display:none removes an element from the layout entirely - I think you want it there, but invisible.

Comment: hmm, if i use opacity, there are major problem with the :hover (because the element is there but invisible, therefore :hover'able/clickable) :-/

Answer (score -2):

Use `overflow:hidden > overflow:visible` , works better, I use like this:

```
example {
 #menu ul li ul {

    background-color:#fe1c1c;
    width:85px;
    height:0px;
    opacity:0;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 10px #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.6s ease;

}

 #menu ul li:hover ul  {

        overflow:visible;
    opacity:1;
    height:140px;
}
```

is better than visible because `overflow:hidden` act exactly like a `display:none`,

Comment: First: please correct your code, its invalid.
Second: overflow is not supported as transition.